# Does the triangle law of vector addition apply to 3D space too?

Tags: vectors

For example, in this parallelepepid:

[image]

You can say the vector $OD=OA+AD$. However, could you also say that $OF=OA+AG+GF$?

Comment: Yes, it does -- it works the same in all dimensions.

Comment: Zhe more interesting question would be wether $OF = OA+OB+OC$. But that is also true.

Comment: That's very interesting. I can see the equivalence too, now that I know it works in 3D space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are completely correct. Nice intuition!